# R version 3.5.1 on Win10 not creating vectors properly

Tags: r

While trying to use RGui Console on Win10 I've encountered some weird behavior. When trying to create vector I get this:

> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
>
> x
>
> [1] 1

or

> y <- c(1:10)
>
> y
>
> [1] 5.5

To the extent of my experience on linux systems, both of the examples above should create a vector of values, not just a single value or apparently median output. Is there some Windows specific code for R?

Comment: Restart and load fresh session doesn’t help?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour happens when `median()` or some other functions (including  `mean()`, as pointed out by [bobbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8562539/bobbel)) are assigned to `c()` (highly inadvisable):

```
> c <- median
> c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
[1] 1
> c(1:10)
[1] 5.5
```

Restarting R session, as [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9406040/roman) already suggested, should solve the problem.

Comment: Well spotted, but note that it would also be true for the mean (and possibly some other functions).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Erasing saved workspace indeed helped!